# Java Database Connection failing, Respone expected

Tags: java, ibm-midrange

I have some `Java` code that is failing; specifically I am trying to make a connection to a database. The code works in general however I have observed that a prompt will be given notifying that the user credentials, the password will expire in 7 days as an example; when this happens the code fails as no response is given. How can I handle this case? I have limited control over user provisioning for the target database, which in this case is an `AS400` server.

Here is my code:

```
Class.forName("com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver");
Connection connection = null;
try {
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You are going to have to get in touch with the system admin and get a service profile for your application that does not expire. That is all you can do. If you don't have a valid user id and password, you can't connect. Or you could prompt for a user id and password each time you start the application, and have the user enter their user id and password. Then you can connect with that.

Answer (score 0):

Use the prompt=false connection property on the JDBC URL to disable the prompting.

connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url+";prompt=false", username, password);

See the following for additional JDBC properties.  http://jt400.sourceforge.net/doc/com/ibm/as400/access/doc-files/JDBCProperties.html